# jQuery - return the most repeated content text by a list of elements with certain class

Tags: jquery, list, count, contains

I need to get the most used content text of elements within a certain class. In my case the most recurrent phrase of  elements: **Service number 1**

```
<div class="service_list">
 <span>Service number 1</span>
 <span>Service number 2</span>
</div>

<div class="service_list">
 <span>Service number 1</span>
 <span> Service number 3</span>
</div>

<div class="service_list">
 <span>Service number 1</span>
 <span> Service number 4</span>
</div>
```

Comment: And where did you get stuck when you tried to write the code to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is below, with explanatory comments in the JavaScript:

```js
// a collection of functions for use:
// create() takes and element-type ('div', 'span'...) along with an Object
// of properties ('className','textContent'...) and then returns the
// created Element with those properties:
let create = (tag, props) => Object.assign(
    // creating the element:
    document.createElement(tag),
    // the Object-literal containing the element's properties:
    props),
  // a simple function to remove existing content from a node,
  // taking a reference to a specific node:
  empty = (node) => {
    // while the node exists and that node has a firstChild:
    while (node && node.firstChild) {
      // we use parentNode.removeChild() to remove the
      // firstChild node; we use this rather than
      // Element.remove() because we wish to remove all
      // nodes, rather than allow inadvertent white-
      // space text-nodes to accumulate:
      node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
    }
  },
  // using an object of functions in order to allow related
  // functions to be grouped/exported as one:
  listServicePopularity = {
    // ascending implies - but I have not written - a corresponding
    // function of descending(); I leave this as an exercise for
    // reader:
    ascending: function() {
        // mentions is the element to which the results will
      // appended, and shown; here we use the get()
      // method to retrieve the first/only element
      // matching the selector:
      let mentions = this.get('.mentions'),
        // services consists of the elements the frequency
        // of which we're going to display in ordered form:
        services = this.getAll('.service_list > span'),
        // usage is ordered frequency of mentions; the
        // function this.getAll() returns an Array of
        // elements, so here we can use Array methods:
        usage = services
        // such as Array.prototype.map():
        .map(
            // using Arrow functions, we're not using 'this'
          // within the function, here we pass a reference
          // to the current Array-element, which is an
          // HTMLElement, and we create a new Array comprised
          // of the text-content of the elements, after we
          // remove leading/trailing white-space with
          // String.prototype.trim():
            (service) => service.textContent.trim()
        )
        // we then use Array.prototype.reduce to convert
        // the Array of Strings into an Object of
        // properties equal to the 
        // Array of [String, Count] pairs:
        .reduce(
            // passing in a reference to the accumulator
          // variable (the empty Object-literal that
          // follows the function declaration, which
          // is modified as the function iterates),
          // and the current Array-value (a string
          // comprised of the text-content of the
          // original element):
          (acc, curr) => {
            // if the accumulator has a property equal to the
            // text of the current Array-element:
            if (acc[curr]) {
                // we increment the property-value of that
              // property:
              acc[curr] = acc[curr] + 1;
            // otherwise:
            } else {
                // we define that property, and initialise its
              // value to 1:
              acc[curr] = 1;
            }
            // and we then return the accumulator for the
            // next iteration:
            return acc;
          // the Object literal - as mentioned - is the
          // initial state of the accumulator:
          }, {});
      // we call the empty() function to remove the existing
      // contents of the mentions element:
      empty(mentions);
      
      // and then call the this.output() function, passing
      // in what should be output, and to where it should
      // be inserted:
      this.output(usage, mentions)
    },
    // creating a document fragment to append multiple elements
    // to one parent-node at once, to minimise redrawing/repainting
    // events:
    fragment: document.createDocumentFragment(),
    // a function which takes a CSS selector and an element Node
    // (which defaults to document if no node is provided), and
    // returns the result of either Element.querySelector() or
    // document.querySelector() with the supplied CSS selector:
    get: (selector, context = document) => context.querySelector(selector),
    // much the same as above, except here we use document.querySelectorAll()
    // (or Element.querySelectorAll(), depending on the context
    // provided), and convert the result of that iterable NodeList
    // as an Array, using an Array-literal and the spread syntax:
    getAll: (selector, context = document) => [...context.querySelectorAll(selector)],
    // the output function; which takes two arguments, an Object
    // of what should be output (key-value pairs), and a reference
    // to the node to which it should be inserted:
    output: function(what, where) {
        // using Object.entries() to obtain a two-dimensional Array
      // of key-value pairs of the Object, and then calling
      // Array.prototype.sort() on the result:
      Object.entries(what).sort(
        // here we use destructuring assignment to map the
        // first array-element (the text of the original
        // element) as aText or bText, and the second element
        // (the frequency with which that text was mentioned)
        // as aCount or bCount.
        // in the function body we simply compare to see if aCount
        // is greater than bCount, and if so we return -1 (so
        // the first element (whose properties are aText, and cCount)
        // precedes the second; otherwise we return 1 which moves
        // after the second element (bText, bCount):
        ([aText, aCount], [bText, bCount]) => aCount > bCount ? -1 : 1
      // we then use Array.prototype.forEach():
      ).forEach(
        // here we again use destructuring to assign the Array-element
        // of the sorted Array into two variables, 'key' and 'value':
        ([key, value]) => {
            // we access the document-fragment, and append a newly-created
          // 'li' element:
          this.fragment.append(create('li', {
            // and assign its text-content to be equal to the interpolated
            // String - using a template-literal - of the 'key' and
            // the 'value':
            textContent: `${key} (${value})`
          }));
        });
      // after the forEach(), once all elements have been appended
      // to the document fragment, we then append that fragment
      // to the 'where' node passed to the function:
      where.append(this.fragment);
    }
  },
  // in order to test the function, we have a randomize function:
  randomize = () => {
    // an Array of service numbers:
    let services = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    // arguably the 'getAll()' function may be better defined
    // outside the listServicePopularity Object, but here we
    // use that function to get an Array of elements, and then
    // iterate over that Array with Array.prototype.forEach():
    listServicePopularity.getAll('.service_list > span').forEach(
        // passing in a reference to the current Array element of the Array
      // of Elements over which we're iterating.
      // in the function body we're setting the text-content of the
      // current Array-element using a Template-literal, which
      // outputs 'Service number <1-4>', using a naive call to
      // Math.random() to generate a number between 1 and 4,
      // this gives a pseudo-random Array-index which we
      // retrieve and add to the String:
      (el) => el.textContent = `Service number ${services[Math.floor( Math.random() * services.length )]}`
    );
    
    // we then call the function to generate, and ultimately output,
    // the service frequency, to have the frequency of the new set
    // of elements generated:
    listServicePopularity.ascending();
  };
  
// binding the randomize() function to the 'click' event on the 
// <button> element:
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', randomize);

// using EventTarget.addEventListener() to bind the anonymous function
// as the event-handler for the 'DOMContentLoaded' event on the
// Window Object:
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
    // calling the function once the DOM has loaded, to show the
  // frequency of services on page-load:
  listServicePopularity.ascending();
});
```

```css
*,::before,::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: system-ui;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  border: 2px solid hsl(120deg 30% 70%);
  display: grid;
  gap: 1em;
  inline-size: clamp(15rem, 50vw, 800px);
  margin-block: 1em;
  margin-inline: auto;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.service_list {
  display: grid;
  gap: inherit;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.service_list > span:first-child {
  text-align: end;
}

.mentions {
  padding-block: 0.5em;
  padding-inline: 1em;
}

.mentions::before {
  content: "Frequency of mentions:";
}

.mentions ::marker {
  color: hsl(120deg 70% 50%);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: italic;
}

.mentions li {
  margin-inline-start: 10%;
  margin-block-start: 0.5em;
  padding-inline-start: 0.4em;
  padding-block: 0.4em;
  position: relative;
}

.mentions li::after {
  content: '';
  background: linear-gradient(to right, hsl(120deg 70% 50% / 1), transparent);
  position: absolute;
  block-size: 3px;
  inline-size: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <button type="button">Randomize Services</button>
  <div class="service_list">
    <span>Service number 1</span>
    <span>Service number 2</span>
  </div>

  <div class="service_list">
    <span>Service number 1</span>
    <span> Service number 3</span>
  </div>

  <div class="service_list">
    <span>Service number 1</span>
    <span> Service number 4</span>
  </div>

  <ol class="mentions"></ol>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tL1jmy0f/2/).

References:

- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [Array literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals).
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).
- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).
- [`document.createDocumentFragment()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment).
- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append).
- [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).
- [`Element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor).
- [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).
- [`Node.firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild).
- [`Node.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild).
- [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).
- [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).
- [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).
- [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).
- [Template-literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).
- [`while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while).

Comment: perfect! It works fine. Thank you now I've good material to work on

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad to have helped!